# Create Panel from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a new to python and pandas. And I have a problem in creating Panel at pandas.

```
def sq_error(w0,w1,x,y):
    return (y - (w0 - w1 * x)) ** 2;


d = dict()
w0 = 50
for w1 in range(0, 10):
    data['height_error'] = data.apply(lambda row: sq_error(w0,w1,row['Weight'], 
                                              row['Height']), axis=1)
    df = data[['height_error','Weight']]
    d['df'] =  df
    d['w1'] = w1


p = pd.Panel(d)
```

I'm getting error 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'

I tried with list

```
d = dict()
w0 = 50
for w1 in range(0, 10):
    data['height_error'] = data.apply(lambda row: sq_error(w0,w1,row['Weight'], 
                                              row['Height']), axis=1)
    l = df[['height_error','Weight']].values.tolist()
    d['df'] = l
    d['w1'] = w1

p = pd.Panel(d)
```

But still getting same error

Comment: where is sq_error() ? is the first line supposed to be `data=dict()` ?

Comment: No it's not. d supposed to store 3-d  dictionary

Comment: data is DataFrame[['Weight','Height']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is trying to access w1 as a dataFrame but it's an int. So of course it does not have a shape attribute

You should write d[w1]=df

```
d = dict()
w0 = 50
for w1 in range(0, 10):
    data['height_error'] = data.apply(lambda row: sq_error(w0,w1,row['Weight'],row['Height']), axis=1)
    l = df[['height_error','Weight']].values.tolist()
    d[w1] = df

p = pd.Panel(d)
```

Thus Pandas will accept it as a dictionary with integer keys and DataFrame values.

Comment: Actually I mean

Comment: data['w1'] = w1
    df = data[['height_error','Weight']]
    df2 = data[['w1']]
    d['df'] =  df
    d['w1'] =  df2